# Using settings.url to differentiate ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to differentiate between ajax requests. I have this code:

```
  $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
      $('#user-content .modal-body').addClass('hide');
      $('#user-content .content-loading').addClass('visible');  
  });
```

I only want this to run for a specific ajax request. I figure I can use `settings.url` and wrap the above code inside an if statement like this.

`if ( settings.url == "ajax/test.html" ) {`

But my the url for this request has a parameter. When I check `settings.url` for this request I will get something like this `/users/user_likes/:id` where id will be a number. How can I match this url when the `:id` will always be different?

Comment: use `match` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 0):

You could split the url and remove the id paramether. Check it out:

```
// split the url
var url_arr = url.split('/'); 
// remove the last url part, wich id paramether is present
url_arr.pop();
// build the url without id paramether
url = url_arr.join('/');
```